# Antenna requirements, transmit vs. receive

Tags: antenna

This question is an extension of this question: [Are antennas specified for a certain frequency?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/624225/are-antennas-specified-for-a-certain-frequency)

I've heard that receive requirements for antennas are much more lax than transmit requirements.  From what I understand transmit antennas should relatively efficiently radiate frequencies within the transmit bandwidth, or there is risk of reflection and potentially equipment damage (in addition to the problem of inefficiently radiating).

Requirements for receive antennas are much less strict.  An antenna can receive signals outside of its specified (tuned / transmit) range, and even efficiently, presumably barring extremes (very long antennas for UHF signals for example)

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: "efficiently" requires some qualification to properly assess. Given an antenna made of linear materials, we have a statement of [reciprocity](https://www.antenna-theory.com/definitions/reciprocity.php) which would state that the numerical efficiency (e.g. dBi gain) would be the same in tx and rx. Are you asking about something different, such as the efficiency of an overall system, which can compensate for poor reception, and if so, can you edit your post to better explain those assumptions?

Answer (score 2):

For efficiently transfer RF energy to/from a circuit, you want an antenna that's impedance is matched to the circuit.  But what happens if they are not matched?

**RX**
For the RX case, you will get poor energy reception. And thus poor signal strength.

**TX**
For the TX case, due to reciprocity, you'll also have poor energy transfer out of the circuit to the antenna.

However, there is an additional consideration for TX, and that is reflections.
When the antenna isn't matched to the circuit there will be some form of a standing wave on the transmission line (between the output amplifier and the antenna).  When that standing wave gets to be too large due to mismatch, then it can damage the amplifier.  A standard way to measure this is called the Standing Wave Ratio (SWR).

When the output power is low (eg. 100mW) then the transistors used in the output amplifier are much more easily able to withstand a large SWR value (large SWR is greater than 2.0) as the voltages are not that great.  However, when you start increasing the output power, then the voltages increase, and the transistors can be damaged if the SWR is too high (ie. antenna is mismatched to the amp).

Answer (score 0):

- Every antenna either Tx or Rx has gain for direction "aka" ( Also Known As ) diversity.  Thus the smaller the beam angle, the greater the focus gain possible.
- Then there are losses for mismatch on impedance vs frequency such as 1/4 wave "pole "(or element or whip) or 1/2 dipole wavelength or feedpoint into a patch resonant dielectric conductor.
- gain of the antenna is relative to a theoretical spherical antenna called isotropic gain. [dBi]
- Since a spherical antenna is not often desired, (or even possible) some minor gains and
  conduction losses are measured for directional antenna to give the
  net results. E.g a perfect half sphere would have a gain of 3 dBi.
- damage occurs when a high power Tx is unprotected against open or short circuit conditions.

### Other info

Ideally BW of Tx and Rx are matched to the spectral BW down to less than -40 dB.  The ability of the Rx depends on the Carrier to Noise Interference ratio or CNR of the Demodulator and if excessive BW or poor CNR from strong interference, then either tuning the 1st stage filter or aiming away from the interference can improve the CNR.

If conversion is used to an IF, you are still dealing with CNR gains from the BW of the IF blocking interfering channel noise.  after demodulation to the baseband signals then it is called SNR.

for example in 2.4G and 5G modems the 1st  indicator is the received signal strength indicator or RSSI and on all mobiles is calibrated from the AGC voltage into dBm where the maximum bit rates e.g. 834 Mbps (? Check) on high speed WiFi,  need much higher RSSI levels (10 to 20 dB) to maintain the BER at this higher SNR than the lower 11 Mbps rates according to Hartley's Laws relating Bit/Baud and the log of signal level [dB]  Then Shannon's Law expanded on this to generalize the error probability.  RSSI in dBm is only available with 3rd party apps, otherwise all you have 3 bars max and less than this implies lower max data rate limits.

So with forward error correction [FEC] almost error free reception above -75 dBm is adequate for 11 To 54 Mbps and to go 10x faster requires at least 10 db more signal.  Multi-path interference will increase the error rates and thus reduce the SNR accordingly and may be extremely sensitive to 1mm displacement or 1 deg aiming of weak signals when in a deadspot from these [Rician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rician_fading) Fading losses.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem